# Error in console page to run javascript on loading page event

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I want the page to go from "hello 1" to "hello 5" when the page loads then it have to swipe up -100vh. It runs well but it shows an error in console in inspect element. Can anyone tell me where am I making mistake?

Following are the error in the console page-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style').
```

I am using the "break;" to end the task but it shows an error for "break;".

**Snippet**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('loading-text');
  var roll = document.getElementById('loading-page');
  var lta = document.getElementById('last_text');
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    texts[i].style.opacity = '0';

    i++;
    if (i === texts.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      lta.className = "last_text_active";
      roll.style.top = '-100vh';
      // break;
    }
    texts[i].style.opacity = '1';
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.on-load-page-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.on-load-page-container #loading-page {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#loading-texts {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.loading-text {
  /* display: none; */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.last_text_active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="on-load-page-container">
  <div id="loading-page">
    <div id="loading-texts">
      <p class="loading-text" style="opacity:1;">hello 1</p>
      <p class="loading-text">hello 2</p>
      <p class="loading-text">hello 3</p>
      <p class="loading-text">hello 4</p>
      <p id="last_text" class="loading-text">hello 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` is used to end a loop or switch, not a function.

Replace `break` with `return` to skip the last line:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('loading-text');
    var roll = document.getElementById('loading-page');
    var lta = document.getElementById('last_text');
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        texts[i].style.opacity = '0';

        i++;
        if (i === texts.length) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            lta.className = "last_text_active";
            roll.style.top = '-100vh';
            return;
        }
        texts[i].style.opacity = '1';
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .on-load-page-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .on-load-page-container #loading-page {
        background-color: #000;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        pointer-events: none;
        position: relative;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    #loading-texts {
        position: fixed;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        z-index: 9999;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .loading-text {
        /* display: none; */
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .last_text_active {
        opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>

<body>

    <div class="on-load-page-container">
        <div id="loading-page">
            <div id="loading-texts">
                <p class="loading-text" style="opacity:1;">hello 1</p>
                <p class="loading-text">hello 2</p>
                <p class="loading-text">hello 3</p>
                <p class="loading-text">hello 4</p>
                <p id="last_text" class="loading-text">hello 5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error in console as it is receiving the `undefined` value of `texts[i]` at the last index

You can add a condition weather the value is not undefined then only change the opacity like this,

```
typeof texts[i] !== 'undefined' && (texts[i].style.opacity = '1');
```

So your JS code will be as follows,

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('loading-text');
  var roll = document.getElementById('loading-page');
  var lta = document.getElementById('last_text');
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    texts[i].style.opacity = '0';

    i++;
    if (i === texts.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      lta.className = "last_text_active";
      roll.style.top = '-100vh';
      // break;
    }
    typeof texts[i] !== 'undefined' && (texts[i].style.opacity = '1');
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Here you're stopping the loop when `i` equals the number of elements in `texts`, but the index won't reach that because JS begins indexes from `0`.

I think you should stop the loop when `i` equals `texts.length - 1` instead:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('loading-text');
  var roll = document.getElementById('loading-page');
  var lta = document.getElementById('last_text');
  var i = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    texts[i].style.opacity = '0';

    i++;
    texts[i].style.opacity = '1';
    if (i === texts.length-1) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      roll.style.top = '-100vh';
      lta.className = "last_text_active"; // Moved this here so it doesn't break the loop
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.on-load-page-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.on-load-page-container #loading-page {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#loading-texts {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.loading-text {
  /* display: none; */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.last_text_active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="on-load-page-container">
  <div id="loading-page">
    <div id="loading-texts">
      <p class="loading-text" style="opacity:1;">hello 1</p>
      <p class="loading-text">hello 2</p>
      <p class="loading-text">hello 3</p>
      <p class="loading-text">hello 4</p>
      <p id="last_text" class="loading-text">hello 5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it works :)